# Removing a lot of rows from a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove non-English tweets from a large dataset in the most efficient way possible. I have tried to create a list of rows that are not English and them removing them, but removing each tweet takes a long time (the `langid.classify()` function is not the problem).

```
def removeLanguage(df):
  rowsToDelete = []
  text = df['tweet'][i]
  try:
    if (langid.classify(text)[0] != 'en' ):
      rowsToDelete.append(i)

      continue
  except ValueError:
    rowsToDelete.append(i)
    continue
   
  for i in rowsToDelete:
    df.drop(i, inplace=True)

newDf = beforeClassification(inputDf).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Is there a more efficient way to remove a set of rows from a DataFrame than `df.drop()`?

Comment: `df.drop` is very efficient. You don't need to drop one row at a time, however. Instead of `for i in rowsToDelete: df.drop(i, inplce=True)` you can just do `df.drop(rowsToDelete, inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

`df.drop` is pretty efficient
but I'd also use anything like this

```
df = df[langid.classify(df.tweet)[0] != 'en' ]
```